# Reading a text file with no delimiter into a vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, integer

I have a text file that has 200 rows, and there are 200 values in every row. The file consists of integers, but they are not separated by any delimiter, not even a space. Here is an example,

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111122222222222222222222222222220000111
1111111111111111111111111111100000000003123333333333333333333333333333300002
0000000000022222222222222222222222222222222211111121212222222222222222111111
```

The file may contain some strings at the beginning, but I want only to read these numbers. I want to be able to count the occurrence of every integer. So, I will read all these numbers into a vector, or a matrix, where every element in the vector is a number in the file. So, the vector must contain 200 * 200 elements. Then, I will calculate the occurrence of every element.

I checked available file reading methods like `textscan`, but I think that `textscan` with this format `C = textscan(fid,'%d %d');` requires specifying %d 200 * 200 times, is this the case, or there is a way to use `textscan`?

I also tried `importdata`, but when I tried to print the result I didn't get the numeric values. It seems that it only reads the first row, because of this line `200x1 double`. Here is the output,

```
A = 
          data: [200x1 double]
      textdata: {6x1 cell}
    colheaders: {[1x107 char]}
```

Can you please tell me what method I can use to read the file described above?

Comment: So each integer is a separate number?  Why not read in as a string, then do a loop  `for j= 1:numel(a_line_of_integers),  x(j) = str2num(a_line_of_integers(j); end` .  And repeat for every row you read in.    Noting in passing that   if you switch to `R`,   `x=as.numeric(strsplit(a_line_of_Integers))`  is much faster and easier

Comment: Exactly, I was just trying to implement that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you wish,  copy my comments into an answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If I post it, it will look that its my answer, but its yours. I strongly suggest that you post it as an answer. It is very helpful.

Comment: OK,... just trying to "donate"  the  points you could earn :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you have with importdata, imports only double values and the headers. You could use the readtable function as follows (I assume 1 header line):

```
datafile='test.txt';
headerlines=1;

%OPTION1
A=readtable(datafile); %from Matlab R2013b
AA=cell2mat(table2array(A(headerlines+1:end,:)));

%OPTION2
A=textread(datafile,'%s'); %from Matlab R2006a
AA=cell2mat(A(headerlines+1:end,:));

%PROCESSING
b=zeros(size(AA));
for k=1:size(AA,1)
  b(k,:)=str2double(regexp(AA(k,:),'\d','match'));
end

%COUNTING
[nelements,centers]=hist(b',0:9);
```

The regular expression does the trick of getting out the numbers to columns:

```
regexp('01112345640','\d','match')
```

This should return a 1x11 cell with the numbers in char-format.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a syntax error here, b(k,:)=regexp(a.data(k),'\d','match'); saying that Undefined function 'regexp' for input arguments of type 'double'. How can I fix it?

Comment: I found regexp. It seems that I was typing regex only. But I'm still getting this error, Undefined function 'readtable' for input arguments of type 'char'. Can you please tel me how to solve it?

Comment: Which Matlab version are you using? readtable is only available from Matlab R2013b and newer (type 'version' in command window to know the version you are using). In datafile is the name of the file you are using, not the file-id!

Comment: I have version 2012. Yes, I've used it as a file name.

Comment: I updated the code for version 2012 and added the counting itself. Does that solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, it is great! I have one question please. I printed the size of array 'b' but I'm getting 199 * 200. Why isn't it 200*200 as in the file? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach:
each integer is a separate number (in the desired output), so read the data in line-by-line as a string, then do a loop

```
for j= 1:numel(a_line_of_integers), 
    x(j) = str2num(a_line_of_integers(j);
end
```

And repeat for every row you read in. Note in passing that if you switch to R, `x=as.numeric(strsplit(a_line_of_Integers))` is much faster and easier